# Mlflow registed model version increment in python

Tags: python, model, version-control, mlflow

I want to keep versions of the model in mlflow but not as version[1,2,3,...]
instead, i want to increment model's versions like 1.1 1.2 and when I feel that there is some major change I want increment to 2.0

please let me know how this can be done.